# Create a 3D zoom effect using jquery and HTML 5

Tags: jquery, html, 3d

I have to create a project similar to the 3D version in http://onemillionreasons.audi.de/index.html ...could anyone tell me the technologies used to create such an effect. Also if its doable with jquery and HTML 5. Or incase there is a lib/plugin i am not aware of. Thanks

Comment: `1.` all resources are in the source of the page you've linked `2.` the page you've linked to is in HTML5, so yes...

Answer (score 1):

There are some great HTML5 libraries such as [Three.JS](http://threejs.org/). You can easily create similar 3D scenes and zoom in/out with the camera object.
[3D Particles Example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_particles_sprites)